# NodeJS: How to load HTML page after GET has returned; Angular.js not being found

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I am very new to both AngularJS and NodeJS. I am trying to get a basic application running that on page load will make a GET call that returns a JSON structure of customers, and the HTML page will then use AngularJS to display that JSON structure into a table.

I can load my HTML with this in my `server.js`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../frontend/app/partials/index.html'));
});
```

And I can make a GET call to retrieve my JSON data on page load with this in my `server.js`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./testData.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

I want to combine those two so that the GET call returns and then the HTML uses that data. How can I do this?

I am also getting a 404 error in the browser for angular.js. I put the path in my `index.html` just like all my other JS files. I have it in `app.use` in my `server.js`. My other JS files and my CSS file can be found fine, but not angular.js. Does anyone know why this is the case? Here is the error

[angular.js not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9ns7.jpg)

Here is my full code:

Server.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

// angular.js gets 404 in browser -- why?
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/bower_components/angular')));
// These files load fine (SimpleController.js, main.css)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/app')));

// This will load the HTML page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../frontend/app/partials/index.html'));
});

// This will return JSON data -- How to combine this with the above GET?
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./testData.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.send(data);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;                                                                                         

    console.log("Server listening on port ", port);
});
```

SimpleController.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['']);                                                                                 

app.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/').then(function (response) {
        $scope.customers = response.data;
    });

});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
     <title>CUSTOMERS</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1> CUSTOMERS </h1>
     <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <form>
           <label>First Name:</label>
              <input type="text" /> <br />
           <label>Last Name:</label>
              <input type="text" /> <br />
           <label>Age:</label>
              <input type="text" /> <br />
           <label>Street:</label>
              <input type="text" /> <br />
           <label>City:</label>
              <input type="text" /> <br />
           <label>State:</label>
              <input type="text" /> <br />
           <label>Zip:</label>
              <input type="text" /> <br />
           <input type="submit" value="Add Customer" />
        </form>

        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <table id="customers">
           <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Street</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>State</th>
              <th>Zip</th>
           </tr>
           <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers">
              <td> {{ cust.firstName }} </td>
               <td> {{ cust.lastName }} </td>
               <td> {{ cust.age }} </td>
               <td> {{ cust.address.street }} </td>
               <td> {{ cust.address.city }} </td>
               <td> {{ cust.address.state }} </td>
               <td> {{ cust.address.zip }} </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <!-- angular.js gets 404 in browser -->
      <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <!-- this loads fine -->
      <script src="../SimpleController.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
So somehow, my index.html could not find angular.js file. I moved the angular.js file from `/src/frontend/bower_components/angular/` into `/src/frontend/app` with the rest of my javascript files. My index.html resides in '`/src/frontend/app/partials/`. I did this along side what suzo suggested of making a '/' route and '/data' route and then calling '/data' inside my controller.

so my next question is ... why can't index.html read angular.js within the /bower_components directory, but it can read it fine within the /app directory?

Comment: Looks like you have two same routes with '/', change the getData route to '/data' or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of combining those two, it's better to keep the getData api separate and render the data after getting the index.html using Angular. 
Now to get that working, you can keep the index.html api as it is and change the getData api to '/data' or something appropriate.

You have not mentioned the api url in the $http request, that is causing the 404 NOT FOUND error. Change it to this and try :

```
app.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('http://localhost:8081').then(function (response) {
     $scope.customers = response.data;
  });

});
```

and, for getData api if the route you have defined is '/data', it would be

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8081/data')
```

It is better to put all the rest api calls in a service/factory instead of having everything in a controller. That is one of the best practices we follow.

Comment: I did this. The HTML page loads at '/' and I get a list of customers in JSON format from '/data' ... but how do I use the response from '/data' to populate my table on the HTML page? Do I need to make the call from within my index.html? Also, adding the url did not resolve my error. I am adding an error screenshot to the question.

Comment: I figured it out; updated the question. Angular.js file could not be found in the directory I had it in for some reason. I moved angular.js into my /app directory with my SimpleController.js file and it was able to read it there. I have no idea why it can't read the other directory ... anyway, after doing that, and doing what you said of making a '/data` I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   customers =  fs.readFile('./testData.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Maybe you'll need to use JSON.stringfy

Answer (score 0):

To *combine* the two, I believe you would have to add the data to the html file before sending it.

If you want to add the JSON dynamically, then consider using AngularJS instead of NodeJS for that purpose.

Create your routes in Angular:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: MainComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

If you don't know what a component is I suggest going through an AngularJS tutorial. Here's one from Angular.io in typescript: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

You can then you services (also explained in the tutorial) to get the data and render it dynamically by using directives like `*ngIf`.

.